# PyQt: Slot execute many times

Tags: python, pyqt, signals, slot

I have a custom widget that I use to create many tabs in a tab widget. In this custom widget I have a button to send messages. This button is connected to a signal like this:

```
signal_mapper = QtCore.QSignalMapper()

self.send_btn.clicked.connect(self.sending_message)
```

in the `sending_message` method I fetch data and I emit a signal to a thread to send the message like this:

```
QtCore.QObject.emit(
    signal_mapper,
    QtCore.SIGNAL("send_message"),
    message)
```

In the send thread (slot receiving)

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(
    signal_mapper,
    QtCore.SIGNAL("send_message"),
    self.send_message
)
```

the problem is when I have many tabs and when I send 'one' message I find that it send number of tabs created * messages (e.g. if I have 3 tabs it sends 3 messages).

**EDIT:**

So this is a fragment of the code:

```
class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, user, user_lst, icon, connexion):
        super(Main, self).__init__()
        self.user_name = user
        self.user_lst = user_lst
        self.icon = icon
        self.connexion = connexion
        ...
        self.show()

    def init_ui(self):
        ...
        self.send_btn.clicked.connect(self.sending_message)
        ...


        self.chat_widget=ChatForm(self.user_name,self.user_lst,self.icon,self.connexion)
        self.tab_widget.addTab(self.chat_widget, self.my_actions.send_file_icon, "topic 1")

    def new_tab(self):
        chat_widget = ChatForm(self.user_name, self.user_lst, self.icon, self.connexion)
        self.tab_widget.insertTab(self.i, chat_widget, "topic")

    def sending_message(self):
        txt = str(self.line_edit.text())
        if txt != "":
            QtCore.QObject.emit(
                signal_mapper,
                QtCore.SIGNAL("send_message"),
                txt)
```

here is sending thread:

```
class SendingThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, client_sock):
        super(SendingThread, self).__init__()
        self.client_socket = client_sock

    def run(self):
        # waiting user to send a message
        QtCore.QObject.connect(
            signal_mapper,
            QtCore.SIGNAL("send_message"),
            self.send_message, QtCore.Qt.UniqueConnection
        )

    def send_message(self, message):
        print("the message as sent", message)
        self.client_socket.send_msg(message)
```

Comment: Are you initializing this Signal in all tabs of the QTabWidget, and then connecting it to some common slot?

A quick workaround could be to not connect it to a common slot (`self.parent().do_something()`), but connect it to an instance method as a slot, which then does:

`if self.isVisible():    self.parent().do_something()`.

This way, it only emits from the currently visible tab.

Comment: I am a beginner in pyqt, pleae can you give me a concrete example

Comment: Few questions (also, can you please not contact me via FB, I know it's public, and I'm willing to help, but only requests here on SO).

Is that `send_btn` defined in the `MainWindow` and not in each, individual tab? That's weird, I'm not sure how that will behave, it should be reparented by each, new tab.

Answer (score 1):

So, you're problem (presumably) is that you have 3 tabs open, and you have the signal bound to each tab instance, so all non-deleted tabs will emit simultaneously. Something can occur like this:

(My code has been done in PySide, I will correct it to PyQt. The core principles remain, although the signal/slot syntax is slightly different).

Notice how I connect the `clicked()` signal not to a `Signal.emit` slot, but to a `method`, which then allows me to set conditions for when the call `Signal.emit`.

```
'''Custom signal example'''

# QtTest is for artificial click events, ignore for implementation
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtTest


class MyTabButton(QtGui.QPushButton):
    '''Custom widget for a tab'''

    signal = QtCore.Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTabButton, self).__init__()

        self.check_visible = True
        self.clicked.connect(self.send_message)

    def send_message(self):
        '''Only send message if object is clicked'''

        if not self.check_visible or self.isVisible():
            self.signal.emit('My message')


def printargs(message):
    '''Slot to print signal message'''

    print(message)



def main():
    '''On exec'''

    tabs = QtGui.QTabWidget()
    for _ in range(3):
        mytab = MyTabButton()
        mytab.signal.connect(printargs)
        tabs.addTab(mytab, 'My Tab {}'.format(_))

    # artificial mouse click at widget 0, the first tab
    # nothing should print
    QtTest.QTest.mouseClick(tabs.widget(0), QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)

    # only one tab should print
    tabs.widget(0).check_visible = False
    QtTest.QTest.mouseClick(tabs.widget(0), QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP = QtGui.QApplication([])
    main()
```

If I run this code, only one tab prints, and only on the second event. This tab widget can be controlled either via `MyTabButton.check_visible` or the widget's visibility (MyTabButton.show()).

Comment: is not clear still now, please can you give me more help. I edit my question by add a code fragment. I hope that you can help me. Thak you.